# Binding anonymous view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

There is a table.
It is formed on the server. The names of some columns are not known beforehand.
For example, the field may be:
"id, Name, field1, field2, field3, etc."

This table must be converted into a model and pass into view.
How to display the model, if it is not known which fields in the table?

I understand correctly, it is necessary to create a dynamic object, such as ExpandoObject (), but then later in view indicate required fields for output?

**View:**

```
@foreach(dynamic item in Model.Items) 
{
  <tr>
     <td>@item.ID</td>
     <td>@item.Name</td>
     <td>@item.??????</td>
       ......
  </tr>
}
```

**EDIT:**

anonymous columns are of type Int32
Before the emergence of the issue class was as follows:

```
public class MyModel
{
      public int ID {get; set;}
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public int Option1 {get; set;}
      public int Option2 {get; set;}
}
```

In consequence of the task has changed and the table must return a different number of "Option". Dynamic class I can do. I do not know how to display dynamic column in View (names are not known in advance, and are known only ID and Name)

Comment: which is the object type Items? you can show us the class definition?

Comment: check this:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/12/18/passing-anonymous-objects-to-mvc-views-and-accessing-them-using-dynamic.aspx

Comment: Use a Dictionary or DataTable

Comment: Dictionary is a good choice